# How to narrow scope on where-on-earth "cheapest place to..." questions

Tags: discussion, scope

My question about [cheapest places for rock-climbing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60029/where-is-the-cheapest-place-on-earth-to-rock-climb) was put on hold. I find it strange because I had narrowed the scope of it to match [this reasonably popular question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/21435/31045) about cheapest places to scuba dive.

I defined costs to exclude ancillary costs (transport, accommodation, *etc.*) , and specifying what infrastructure I was looking for (a place with various routes that have bolts and hangars).

Can someone give me advice on how to narrow it further?

Comment: I think your question is fine, and I voted to re-open.

Comment: I think it's fine as well (particularly with the comparison to the linked question) although a completely definitive answer may be out of the question. Anyway, I just cast the last re-open vote so we'll see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The question is Open at present and with net +5 at the moment and two answers (plus one deleted) seems likely to stay that way. It was reopened without any editing so we are back to the regular issue that TSE has little by way of a "common mind" (lacks consensus).

Regarding:

> Can someone give me advice on how to narrow it further?

This was not required and the alternative - ask abut the Q on meta - was probably always likely to be more efficacious. Had it not been, then perhaps a separate question for each continent *might* have worked.